# Why is brute forcing DH private key harder than calculating public key?

Tags: tls, key-management, key-exchange

Assuming shared parameters: prime ***p*** base ***g***

Alice's private key is ***a*** and her public key is ***A***, which is ***g*** ^ ***a*** mod ***p***

Calcuating ***A*** requires ***g*** * ***g*** * ***g***... ***a*** times. Modulus is applied whenever necessary.

If an attacker knows ***A***, ***p***, and ***g***, why is it hard to calculate ***a***?  Would he not just keep multiplying on ***g*** and seeing if he's achieved ***A***?

I am not seeing what is fundamentally different between Alice's computation to create ***A*** from ***a***, and Eve's computation to brute force ***a*** knowing ***A***.  Can anyone provide some insight here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing the public key is a problem of *modular exponentiation*, which can be done in O(log(e)) steps via [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

On the other hand, finding the private key is the *discrete logarithm* problem, for which no equally efficient algorithm exists. You just have to run through all the possible values and try them all. There are some better algorithms, such as Pollig-Hellman and Big Step-Little Step, but they are generally not applicable for the general case (the former is only efficient for numbers that decompose into small primes, for example)

This means that computing a modular exponent is vastly faster than a discrete logarithm. For a very large exponent, this effectively makes the exponentiation a one-way function.

...unless, of course, you have a [quantum computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm)!

Comment: time ​ -> ​ "modular multiplications" ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I'll go with "steps" for now; it all means the same thing, really.

Comment: Also, I'll expand upon this answer when I get home - I tried to look up my notes from crypto, but the mobile OneNote app just shows the word "[Equation]" 25 times in every page...

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks!  I did not know that the exponentiation could be done in less steps than e.  Makes perfect sense.